# Display Graph System on WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

So I want to be able to display a weighted graph in windows forms and I was wondering if there was any libraries for that available anywhere.

Ideally I would be able to add nodes and positions to an adjacency list with weights and the library would display the system with varied colors for different weights.

Comment: You might want to check out https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/. StackOverflow isn't meant for library recommendations, though.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/home?forum=csharpgeneral,windowsuidevelopment&filter=alltypes&brandIgnore=True&sort=relevancedesc&searchTerm=graphing may be a better place to look